# Flask flash and redirect - shows response in devtools but no pageload

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

New to flask here ... my problem is that I'm trying to check if a response is empty, and if so flash a message.  With the below code, I can see that the redirect goes through and the subsequent GET responds with the correct html in dev tools, but the page is not loaded, it stays on the current page (which also happens to be layout.html, not sure if this is an issue, my intent is to simply reload this page to show the flashed message).

**Relevant Flask:**

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('layout.html')

@app.route('/query',methods=['POST'])
def query():
    start=request.json['start']
    end=request.json['end']
    name=request.json['name']
    sql="select some stuff"
    data_list = []
    stuff=cur.execute(sql)
    for row in stuff:
        data_list.append(row[0])
    if not data_list: 
        flash('No balances for selected client/dates')
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))
    return json.dumps(data_list) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'secretkeyhere'
    app.run(debug=True,host='127.0.0.1',port=8000)
```

**Relevant portion of the html to avoid a wall of text**

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
   {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="flashed_message" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      {{message}}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

**And lastly.... AJAX:**

```
$(function(){
  $("[type=submit]").click(
        function(){
            // event.preventDefault()
            $(".container").hide()         
            var startdate=$('#datetimepicker1').val()
            var enddate=$('#datetimepicker2').val()            
            var name=$('#mhh').val()
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/query",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(response) {
               console.log('worked!')
               return {'start':response.start,'end':response.end,'name':response.name}
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log('didn\'t work')
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: AJAX ...totally spaced out and didn't include in the original post (now updated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see of your code it looks like you're redirecting the AJAX call. Essentially your AJAX call will load your index, and not the browser itself (which is what you want).

Inside your AJAX, try changing your error function to

```
error: function() {
    document.location.reload()
}
```

Then, alter your if not data_list block to:

```
if not data_list:
    flash('No balances for selected client/dates')
    return Response(status=500)
```